# How to perform conditional insert based on row count?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, insert, concurrency

I'm using Postgres 9.3, and I need to prevent inserts into a table based on a count of specific rows already in the table. Here's the table:

```
                                      Table "public.team_joins"
     Column      |           Type           |                            Modifiers                             
-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 id              | integer                  | not null default nextval('team_joins_id_seq'::regclass)
 team_id         | integer                  | not null
Indexes:
    "team_joins_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "team_joins_team_id" btree (team_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "team_id_refs_teams_id" FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

So, for example, if a team with id 3 only allows 20 players, and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM team_joins WHERE team_id = 3` is equal to 20, no players should be able to join team 3. What's the best way to handle this and avoid concurrency issues? Should I use a `SERIALIZABLE` transaction to insert, or can I just use a `WHERE` clause like this in the insert statement?

```
INSERT INTO team_joins (team_id)
VALUES (3)
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM team_joins WHERE team_id = 3
) < 20;
```

Or is there a better option that I'm not considering?

Comment: Are you *always* inserting single rows to `team_joins` or can it be a whole set at once? Is there a table `team` (or similar) with *unique* rows per `team_id`? Aside: Postgres 9.3? Have you considered upgrading?

Comment: For now I'm always inserting single rows, but in the future it will likely be necessary/desirable to insert a whole set at once. There is indeed a `teams` table with an `id` column that is the primary key.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Typically, you have a `team` table (or similar) with a unique `team_id` column.
Your FK constraint indicates as much: `... REFERENCES teams(id)` - so I'll work with `teams(id)`.

Then, to avoid complications (race conditions or deadlocks) under concurrent write load, it's typically simplest and cheapest to take a **write lock on the parent row** in `team` and then, in the same transaction, write the child row(s) in `team_joins` (`INSERT` / `UPDATE` / `DELETE`).

```
BEGIN;

SELECT * FROM teams WHERE id = 3 FOR UPDATE;  -- write lock

INSERT INTO team_joins (team_id)
SELECT 3                -- inserting single row
FROM   team_joins
WHERE  team_id = 3
HAVING count(*) < 20;

COMMIT;
```

Example for *single* row `INSERT`. To process a whole set at once, you need to do more; see below.

One might suspect a corner case problem in the `SELECT`. What if there is *no* row with `team_id = 3`, yet? Wouldn't the `WHERE` clause cancel the `INSERT`?
It wouldn't, because the `HAVING` clause makes this an aggregation over the whole set which *always* returns exactly one row (which is eliminated if there are 20 or more for the given `team_id` already) - *exactly* the behavior you want. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP)

> If a query contains aggregate function calls, but no `GROUP BY` clause,
> grouping still occurs: the result is a **single group row (or perhaps no
> rows at all, if the single row is then eliminated by `HAVING`)**. The same
> is true if it contains a `HAVING` clause, **even without any aggregate
> function calls or `GROUP BY` clause**.

Bold emphasis mine.

The case where no parent row is found is no problem either. Your FK constraint enforces referential integrity anyway. If `team_id` is not in the parent table, the transaction dies with a foreign key violation either way.

*All* possibly competing write operations on `team_joins` have to follow the same protocol.

In the `UPDATE` case, if you change the `team_id`, you would lock the source *and* the target team.

Locks are released at the end of the transaction. Detailed explanation in this closely related answer:

- [How to atomically replace a subset of table data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166816/how-to-atomically-replace-a-subset-of-table-data/166912#166912)

In Postgres **9.4** or later, the new, weaker **`FOR NO KEY UPDATE`** may be preferable. Also does the job, less blocking, potentially cheaper. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html)

> Behaves similarly to `FOR UPDATE`, except that the lock acquired is
> weaker: this lock will not block `SELECT FOR KEY SHARE` commands that
> attempt to acquire a lock on the same rows. This lock mode is also
> acquired by any `UPDATE` that does not acquire a `FOR UPDATE` lock.

Another incentive to consider upgrading ...

#### Insert multiple players of the same team

Usefully assuming you have a column `player_id integer NOT NULL`. Same locking as above, plus ...

Short syntax:

```
INSERT INTO team_joins (team_id, player_id)
SELECT 3, unnest('{5,7,66}'::int[])
FROM   team_joins
WHERE  team_id = 3
HAVING count(*) < (21 - 3);  -- 3 being the number of rows to insert
```

The set-returning function in the `SELECT` list does not comply with standard SQL, but it's perfectly valid in Postgres.
<sub>Just don't combine multiple set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list before Postgres 10, which finally fixed related unexpected behavior.</sub>

Cleaner, more verbose, standard SQL doing the same:

```
INSERT INTO team_joins (team_id, player_id)
SELECT team_id, player_id
FROM  (
   SELECT 3 AS team_id
   FROM   team_joins
   WHERE  team_id = 3
   HAVING count(*) < (21 - 3)
   ) t
CROSS JOIN (
   VALUES (5), (7), (66)
   ) p(player_id);
```

That's ***all or nothing***. Like in a Blackjack game: one too many and the whole `INSERT` is out.

#### Function

To round it off, all of this could conveniently be encapsulated in a `VARIADIC` PL/pgSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_add_players(team_id int, VARIADIC player_ids int[])
  RETURNS bool
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM teams WHERE id = 3 FOR UPDATE;         -- lock team
-- SELECT * FROM teams WHERE id = 3 FOR NO KEY UPDATE;  -- in pg 9.4+

   INSERT INTO team_joins (team_id, player_id)
   SELECT $1, unnest($2)                                -- use $1, not team_id
   FROM   team_joins t
   WHERE  t.team_id = $1                                -- table-qualify to disambiguate
   HAVING count(*) < 21 - array_length($2, 1);
   -- HAVING count(*) < 21 - cardinality($2);           -- in pg 9.4+

   RETURN FOUND;                                        -- true if INSERT
END
$func$;
```

[About `FOUND`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS)

Call (note the simple syntax with a *list* of values):

```
SELECT f_add_players(3, 5, 7, 66);
```

Or, to pass an actual *array* - note the `VARIADIC` key word again:

```
SELECT f_add_players(3, VARIADIC '{5,7,66}');
```

Related:

- [How to use an array as argument to a VARIADIC function in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158078/how-to-use-an-array-as-argument-to-a-variadic-function-in-postgresql/158088#158088)
- [Pass multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19204560/939860)

Comment: I should clarify further that, even though it will be necessary to insert a whole set of players in the future, each set will always be players joining a single team. It will never be necessary for a single transaction to insert multiple players into different teams. I assume this means that the write locking portion of your answer would not be affected.

Comment: @AlienBishop: Yup, that's exactly what this means.

Comment: I don't think this works. You're not locking the table's rows that don't exist before the `INSERT` statement. So you can insert extra rows there. And, even during the `INSERT ... query` I don't think you're guaranteed that nothing touches the table before the INSERT finishes and after the `count(*)`.

Comment: @Evan: Seems like you see only one table. I lock in `team` and write to `team_joins`. This technique is proven good.

Comment: @Evan: The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html) for `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` says, "...other transactions that attempt...SELECT FOR UPDATE...of these rows will be blocked until the current transaction ends." So it seems like Erwin's technique will work.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter is right, I didn't see another table.  despite him having it bolded. =( My bad.

Comment: @Erwin what happens when there are no rows selected in `SELECT * FROM teams WHERE id = 3 FOR UPDATE;`? Is the lock held anyway preventing other transactions to enter as @Alien stated above?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek: No rows found, means no lock with `FOR UPDATE`. But since there is a FK constraint, this would raise a foreign key violation exception anyway. We only want to insert if the parent row exists.

Comment: @AlienBishop: You may be interested in the updated function.

Comment: That technique to take a write lock on the parent row is great. I've been looking all day at various complicated solutions and this is by far the simplest and most elegant one. Thanks a lot for sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering your comment

> For now I'm always inserting single rows, but in the future it will
>   likely be necessary/desirable to insert a whole set at once

I don't know how you store a player has joined a team or not. So i will call them "newplayer"
If you have a lot of "newplayers" waiting for joining a team, I would suggest this kind of query to now how many team you have to create :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER () -1)/20) +1) 
FROM newplayer
```

It returns a list of number from 1 to needed max. If you have 55 players without team, it will return '1','2','3'. Then you can join on this request to insert your 3 teams at once.

For you team_joins, something like this :

```
WITH match AS (SELECT ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER () -1)/20) +1) AS teamId, newplayers.id as playerId)
INSERT INTO team_joins (team_id, player_id)
match.teamId, match.playerId
FROM match
```

Up to you at change '20' into 'team.limit' and substract count of already inserted joins for each team.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this atomically..

```
INSERT INTO team_joins (team_id)
SELECT team_id
FROM team_joins
GROUP BY team_id
HAVING count(*) < 20;
```

However, I'm not sure that the best way because of concurrency concerns. Without `SERIALIAZABLE` it's still possible but *extremely* unlikely under normal workloads, that the select will complete before the `INSERT` starts. My favorite way to solve the concurrency problem is not to `INSERT` or `DELETE` concurrently unless you have to. Instead, to pre-insert when you add the team and allocate the team members. Without `SERIALIZABLE`, there are lots of edge cases. With `SERIALIZABLE` you have to replay transactions -- both of those solutions are more concrete and but far more complex.

As a general rule, it's easy and natural to lock/protect rows and guarantee against modification during a transaction. It's complex to protect tables from INSERTs.

You may find my other answer interesting [*Strategy for concurrent group bookings?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/160215/2639)

Comment: If I use `SERIALIZABLE` in this case, do I actually have to replay transactions? Wouldn't a serialization failure indicate that the failed `INSERT` violated the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: No, what if someone added one row to the table after the `count(*)`. PostgreSQL doesn't know what the count(*) is testing against, just that it's stale in one transaction.

Comment: My advice is to avoid `SERIALIZABLE` like the plague. After you go down that route, everything has to be `SERIALIZABLE`. Good luck with that. I acknowledge others feel differently about this mode though.