# Looking for feedback on database design for availability

Tags: postgresql, database-design

**TL;DR** - Is my approach of using separate `date` and `time` columns correct given that the availability of a user is set on a day-of-week basis and is independent of the calendar date.

---

I'm using `PostgreSQL 9.5` and working on a booking / availability project where a user can set their daily availability for a given date range; for instance:

```
User: 1

Range: 04/30/2018 - Infinity

SUN:  12:30:00 - 16:00:00
MON:  08:00:00 - 23:59:59
TUE:  00:00:00 - 23:59:59
WED:  00:00:00 - 16:30:00
THU:  08:00:00 - 23:59:59
FRI:  12:00:00 - 23:59:59
SAT:  12:00:00 - 23:59:59
```

In order to accomplish this, I was considering setting up the following tables, and I would like feedback/constructive criticism on my approach:

**users**

```
    Column     |            Type             |                     Modifiers                      
---------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id            | bigint                      | not null default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 email         | character varying           | not null default ''::character varying
 created_at    | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at    | timestamp without time zone | not null
 first_name    | character varying(255)      | 
 last_name     | character varying(255)      |
```

**date_range**

```
   Column   |            Type             |                      Modifiers                      
------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id         | bigint                      | not null default nextval('ranges_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
 start_date | date                        | not null
 end_date   | date                        | 
 user_id    | bigint                      | not null
```

**time_range**

```
   Column      |            Type             |                        Modifiers                        
---------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 id            | bigint                      | not null default nextval('time_slots_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at    | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at    | timestamp without time zone | not null
 date_range_id | bigint                      | not null
 start_time    | time                        | not null
 end_time      | time                        | not null
 weekday_id    | integer                     | not null
```

The goal of which would be to return `users` who have availability within a given date, and time range.

```
Start Date: Monday, April 30th
Start Time: 10:00 AM

End Date: Wednesday, May 2nd
End Time: 2:45 PM
```

For instance, given the above input and initial dataset, I would want to perform a search which would return a  `user` record with an `id = 1`, because they are available within the full 52.75 hr range of the input parameters.

* I've neglected to include Time Zone related considerations for the sake of brevity.

I'm also considering using a `daterange` type for the `start_date` and `end_date`. And had considered using a `tsrange` for the `start_time` and `end_time`; however, `tsrange` includes the date, and I didn't think that would be the best option considering that `time_ranges` are date-independent – That being said, I'm open to anything which makes this more efficient / easier to navigate.

Additionally, I'm guessing I'll need to use `relational division` when building the query?

**EDIT** I've found some good tutorials on similar setups, but they have all dealt with bookings where the event has a set start and end date and time. My understanding of what I'm trying to accomplish (and perhaps that understanding is incorrect) is that, a user needs to set general availability on a day-of-week basis as opposed to specific calendar dates, in order to avoid having a ton of repeating ranges.

I'm totally open to other setups or even just links to resources which can help me gain a better understanding of how to approach this problem.

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/160215/2639 ?

Comment: @EvanCarroll - They are similar, but in this situation, `time_ranges` are date-independent, where as in that example, a reservation is make for an event that has a specified date and time. That's not to say that my approach is correct though, which is why I was looking for feedback as my SQL-fu is far from proficient.